# Why is directory pg_commit_ts empty?

Tags: postgresql, directory-structure, postgresql-13

I have installed PostgreSQL 13 and created a new database, a few tables and inserted data on those tables. I used transactions to insert data, but still `pg_commit_ts` is empty.

what is the function of this directory and why is it empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory is empty because `track_commit_timestamp` is `off`. It is used to persist commit timestamps.

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz Albe. It also means that postgreSQL doesn't store commit timestamp information with rows/tuples instead relevant xmin and xmax.

Comment: No, timestamps are never stored with tuples.